# Redirect to success url - Stripe

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I'm facing with a problem in my code.

I'm building a checkout session on Stripe, and I want to redirect costumer after the payment is successful.

But I'm receiving Cannot get /success

Here is my code:

Button to send parameters to stripe \/

```
const handleStripe = () =>{
            await fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(lista)
                    }).then((res)=>{
                        return res.json();
                    }).then((response)=>{
                        if(response){
                            return window.location.href = response.url
                        }
                    })
                }
```

Server.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('public'));

const success = 'http://localhost:3000/success';
const cancel = 'http://localhost:3000/cancel';
const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:3000';

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const lineItems = req.body
  console.log(req.body)
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: lineItems ,
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${success}`
    }),
    cancel_url: `${cancel}`,
  });
  return res.json({url: session.url});
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Running on port 3000'));
```

I tried to change my server.js to fix it, but I couldn't find any solution

Comment: Those redirect variables are redirecting back to port `:3000` which (it appears) is your backend server. What do those routes look like on the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any pages that are being served on `http://localhost:3000/success` path? Based on the code you've shared so far, it looks like you're running your server on port `:3000` but it doesn't have any function definition that handles request on `/success` route.

Once the checkout session is complete, it tries to redirect to that page/route but isn't finding anything. Hence the error. You'd want to make sure you're redirecting a valid path.

There's a youtube tutorial you can refer to if you're unsure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQ5jccnZ2Ow

Comment: Its weird because i'm giving the right path to success page. When i turn off the server, page (sucess) works fine, but when the server is on i receive this message.. cannot get /success